Spring Data OpenSearch Unable to Convert Value of @Timestamp to Java Instant
Hi I have field in my opensearch index of @timestamp which looks like this JSON in the document: “@timestamp”: “2024-06-03T20:31:06.40402165Z”,. I tried to retrive the value with the following field in my spring data opensearch document record:
@Field(name = "@timestamp" type = FieldType.Date) Instant atTimestamp,

but I am getting the following error:
2024-06-14 14:13:47 org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ConversionException: Unable to convert value '2024-06-03T20:30:17.058647704Z' to java.time.Instant for property 'atTimestamp'
To fix this I tried adding a pattern to field like this: pattern = "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssssssssZ but his gives the following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditLogRepository' defined in com.my.java.project defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on OpenSearchConfig: Too many pattern letters: s
So I then tried to add a format with DateFormat:
format = {
   DateFormat.date_time_no_millis,
   DateFormat.strict_date_optional_time_nanos,
   DateFormat.date_optional_time,
   DateFormat.epoch_millis
 })

but this just gave the original error. Now I am just throwing patterns at the wall and hopping something sticks but nothing seem to work.
Here is what I tried so far:
  @Field(
             name = "@timestamp",
             type = FieldType.Date,
             pattern = {
               "uuuu-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX]",
               "uuuu-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXZ]",
               "uuuu-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXZD]",
               "uuuu-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX]Z",
               "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXZ",
               "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXZ",
               "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",
               "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXZ",
               "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXZD",
               "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss,s'T'ZD",
               "YYYY-MM-DD['T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXZ]",
               "YYYY-MM-DD['T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXZD]",
               "YYYY-MM-DD['T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX]Z",
               "YYYY-MM-DD['T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX]ZD",
               "uuuu-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX]ZD"
             })
         Instant atTimestamp,

Does anyone know how I am supposed to properly convert this? Thanks for any help in advance

JDBC does not map any SQL standard types to java.time.Instant. The SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE maps to java.time.OffsetDateTime. From there, you can call OffsetDateTime#toInstant to obtain an Instant object. The SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE maps to java.time.LocalDateTime.

ok I swaped the field to OffsetDateTime and got the same error:
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ConversionException: Unable to convert value '2024-06-03T20:30:17.058647704Z' to java.time.OffsetDateTime for property 'atTimestamp

Does it work if you have only 6 decimal places with DateFormat.strict_date_optional_time_nanos? The documentation from Elastic Search seems a little hazy on what 'nanos' means in that the example for https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#strict-date-time-nanos has only 6 decimal places, which I would call micros.

I think the format you want is uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSX.
Here is a test which passes:
    @Test
    @DisplayName("should convert nanos")
    void shouldConvertNanos() {
        ElasticsearchDateConverter converter = ElasticsearchDateConverter.of("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSX");
        LocalDateTime parsed = converter.parse("2024-06-03T20:30:17.058647704Z", LocalDateTime.class);

        assertThat(parsed).isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 6, 3, 20,30, 17, 58647704));
    }

It would also work to truncate your dates at six decimal places: this test also passes:
    @Test
    @DisplayName("should convert millis")
    void shouldConvertMillis() {
        ElasticsearchDateConverter converter = ElasticsearchDateConverter.of(DateFormat.strict_date_optional_time_nanos);
        LocalDateTime parsed = converter.parse("2024-06-03T20:30:17.058647Z", LocalDateTime.class);

        assertThat(parsed).isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 6, 3, 20,30, 17, 58647000));
    }


Yes, thanks I was going crazy. I couldn't quite figure out the pattern and would never have though the Z would map to X.
